# How can I use keys and values from jq to generate a bash associative array?

Tags: json, bash, jq, associative-array

From Json structure, I want a specific dictionary. From key's color yellow or red, I add id value.

```json
[
  {
    "id": "9b058640",
    "type": "db",
    "color": "red",
    "host": "db1"
  },
  {
    "id": "0u858640",
    "type": "db",
    "color": "yellow",
    "host": "db2"
  },
  {
    "id": "0ui9k40",
    "type": "net",
    "color": "red",
    "host": "net1"
  },
  {
    "id": "5ty87a",
    "type": "net",
    "color": "yellow",
    "host": "net2"
  }
]
```

So  I want to get the X dictionary

```
X=(
   ['yellow']="9b058640 5ty87a"
   ['red']="9b058640 0ui9k40"
 )
```

I could parse by value :

```
jq -c '.[] | select(.color | contains("red"))'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for `.`, `source`, `eval` or even looping in bash. All you need is `declare` and `jq`, which can construct the declaration using [escaping](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Formatstringsandescaping) with `@sh` and [string interpolation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Stringinterpolation-%5C%28foo%29):

```sh
declare -A X="($(
  jq -r '
    ("yellow", "red") as $color 
    | @sh "[\($color)]=\(map(select(.color == $color).id) | join(" "))"
  ' input.json
))"
```

```sh
$ echo "${X[yellow]}"
0u858640 5ty87a

$ echo "${X[red]}"
9b058640 0ui9k40
```

Comment: Thanks you very, it works, it was impossible to do it by myself !!

Comment: Excellent answer! jq really is an amazing tool, so well designed / considered - so impressed with it and what can be done with simple bash / jq

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `@tsv` operator in jq to emit tab-separated output, which a bash `while read` loop can easily parse as input.

Assuming your input JSON is in the variable `s`:

```
declare -A X=( )

while IFS=$'\t' read -r color id; do
  X[$color]+="$id "
done < <(jq -r '.[] | [.color, .id] | @tsv' <<<"$s")
```

The above does take a minor shortcut in that it leaves a trailing space after each item. If that's unacceptable for some reason, you can always go through the array and clean it up after the fact with a second loop:

```
for color in "${!X[@]}"; do
  X[$color]=${X[$color]%" "}
done
```

You can see this running in the sandbox at https://replit.com/@CharlesDuffy2/IndigoRemoteEngineering

---

Alternately, using `eval`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[0-3].*) echo "ERROR: bash 4.0+ required" >&2; exit 1;; esac
declare -A X=( )
eval "$(
  jq -r '
    reduce .[] as $item ({}; .[$item.color] += [$item.id])
    | to_entries[]
    | "X[\(.key | @sh)]=\(.value | join(" ") | @sh)"
  '
)" <file.json
```

Comment: Thanks very much for you replying, but I edit the question because of structure of json, because there is comma , and bracket []

Comment: In that case just `.[] |` needs to be added to the query; updating appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
declare -A a
. <(jq -r '"a[\(.color)]+=${a[\(.color)]+ }\(.id)"' file.json)
```

Provides:

```
$ declare -p a
$ declare -A a=([red]="9b058640 0ui9k40" [yellow]="0u858640 5ty87a" )
# or
$ echo "${a[red]}"; echo "${a[yellow]}"
9b058640 0ui9k40
0u858640 5ty87a
```

Explanation:

- Construct the following bash code in `jq`:
- `a[color]+=${a[color]+ }id`
- `${a[color]+ }` expands to  , only if `a[color]` is empty.
- `"\(.id)"` is jq string interpolation - its replaced with the value of `.id`
- use `.` and a process sub to source this code

Comment: Using `eval`, `source` or `.` on generated code introduces security exposure that needs to be mitigated: Use `| @sh` inside the `\( ... )` segments to ensure that hostile IDs or color names can't be used to attack the system's security. You don't want a JSON file saying that something is colored `$(rm -rf ~)` to delete your home directory.

Comment: Thanks very much for you replying, but I edit the question because of structure of json, because there is comma , and bracket []

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The issues is escaping `.color` inside the array subscript. The quotes aren't removed. However a I found a version that works similarly.

Comment: @dan, ...I added my own `eval`-based version that avoids the whitespace issue -- see addendum to other answer.

Comment: @dan, see https://replit.com/@CharlesDuffy2/SphericalWhirlwindDebuggers#main.sh -- yes, there's an error message, **but the injected code still gets run**. And if you made it `$(rm -rf ~; echo hi)`, then there wouldn't be an error message at all -- the reason there was an error message is that the stdout from rm was empty, and an empty string isn't a valid key.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Oh yeah I did know that. This behaviour of `declare` is not well documented IMO. `declare '$(echo foo; touch foo)=bar'` doesn't create the variable or file `foo` (it does with double quotes), but `declare -A 'a[$(echo foo; touch foo)]='` creates `a[foo]` and `./foo`. Only subscripts are evaluated.